# Unable to keep the CSS theme using jQuery Mobile when swapping div content

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I think the title is self-explanatory, but here we go: I'm new to jQuery and mobile development. While using jQuery Mobile standard .css file (which explanation I actually found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/theme-control-jquery-mobile.html), I'm trying to dynamically swap a div content to another through a JS function but the css theme won't carry over. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
      <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function callNext () {
        $('#div_auth').html($('#div_functions').html());
      }
      </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="div_main">

      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Phonegap Test</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content" id="div_auth">   
        <form name="fields" action="">
          Name: <input type="text" id="login" name="login"/><br> 
          <button type="button" onclick="callNext();">Send</button>
        </form> 
      </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="div_functions">
      <form name="functions" action="">
        <button type="button">Client List</button> <br>
        <button type="button">Price List</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

So when div_auth content is loaded, it loads data-theme="a" by default (I suppose this is implied in div_main and not div_auth, but anyway). However, when I click the button, even when I specify a data-theme for div_functions, the buttons will be rendered as standard, "css-less" html buttons.

Just a note before anyone begins to wonder, I need to call the div swap through a JS function since this is just a simplification of a Phonegap/Cordova application I'm beginning to develop and this call emulates how it actually works. However, I tested the very code above and it (mis)behaves just the same

**Edit:**

In order to make some sense out of Scott's answer, I've tried a little something:

```
<div data-role="content" id="div_auth" data-theme="b">  
  <form name="fields" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" id="login" name="login"/><br> 
    <button data-theme="a" type="button" onclick="callNext();">Send</button>
  </form>   
</div>
```

As you all can see, I explicitly added data-theme="b" to div_auth and data-theme="a" to the wrapped button. To my surprise, it actually worked, where div_auth assumes the blue theme while the button is rendered in a blackish color. However, using the same approach in the second div (div_functions), even using the very same themes resulted in buttons with no css styling attached:

```
<button data-theme="a" type="button">Price List</button>
```

still renders a "stale button".

Answer (score 0):

The css styles that match `#div_functions` must also match `#div_auth`.  Your javascript line doesn't copy any styles, just content.  When that content is appended to `#div_auth`, it takes on whatever CSS styles match that element, which in this case seems to be nothing.  The easiest thing to do would be to create CSS styling for `button`, which will match your button tags no matter where they are in the DOM.

Comment: Hey Scott, I've edited my original post in order to address to your answer.